# How to call push notification Every day at 23:00 by using UILocalnotification

Tags: objective-c

I want to implement push notification by using UILocalNotification.
So I write this code, but it called multiple times and it times is not 23:00 but 23:13,23:34,23:xx

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{      
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];


    [componentsForFireDate setHour: 23] ; //for fixing 23PM hour
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;
    UILocalNotification* notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc]
                                        init];

    NSLog(@"____date is %@",[calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate]);
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"hello";


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
```

I want to fix 23:00 and call once.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to schedule a local notification (at 23:00) when iOS wakes up your app during background app refresh? Background app refresh is not guaranteed, and you can't be sure when your app will be woken up. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to call method every day at 23:00. Do you know how to implement it ?

Comment: What method exactly do you want to call everyday? You can schedule a local notification at 23:00 everyday to alert the user, but a local notification does not run any code.